# Using custom fonts in web browsers with node-canvas

Tags: node-canvas

In node-canvas, I understand that you can use custom fonts that are not installed as system fonts by using `registerFont` as per the documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas#registerfont

This function takes the path to a **local** font file as the first parameter.

In a web browser implementation, is there any way to achieve something similar? I can use a font if it's installed, but I'd like to be able to download and register a custom font instead.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to `registerFont` in HTML Canvas is the CSS Font API. There's an example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font#Loading_fonts_with_the_CSS_Font_Loading_API

```
const f = new FontFace('test', 'url(x)');
await f.load();
ctx.font = '12px test';
```